# How can I omit this variable from the URL query string

Tags: php, ajax

Good day sir / ma'am im a newbie programmer, is their a way that page number will not see in the url? or is their anybody know some link about this question alike?

all I want is the page number will not see in this url pagination2.php?page=6
is their a way I will use POST rather than GET in getting the page number?
a pagination(ajax-php) using post of xmlhttp?
Im very sorry if my english is bad. Please dont negative my question. Im a newbie. :D

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hey you're new that's cool, welcome!. For you to get a response here you will have to elaborate on what you've tried then we can help you from that.

Comment: P.S It's bad SEO practices to omit a page number

Comment: Ajax is your friend. http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-jquery-ajax-php/ example

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do that using ajax without showing your page number in url:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<div class="page" data-page='1'>1</div>
<div class="page" data-page='2'>2</div>
<div class="page" data-page='3'>3</div>
<div class="page" data-page='4'>4</div>

</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('.page').click(function(e){

    var page=$(this).attr('data-page');

    var data={pageNum:page};

        $.ajax({
            url:'target.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:data,
            success:function(datar){
             alert(datar);
            }

        })

        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

This will send the page number to the php file and receive data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- pretty urls (only if what bothers you is the ugly query string) , if you use Apache, then you'll need mod-rewrite.
- pass the data in the request body (yes, even if you use a GET request, you can pass data in the request body).

I don't recommend using the POST method to retrieve data, as POST is a "not secure method" (because POST was designed to modify resources, not to retrieve it, it's a good practice to respect the HTTP verbs semantics).

**EDIT:**
The first reason to use GET instead of POST is that GET requests are usually cached, so it'd s good idea if you want food performance.

Another good reason is code readibility. It's easier to understand the purpose of the requests if the HTTP verbs semantics is preserved.

Contrary to what a lot of people says, is possible to send data in the request body when you use the GET verb instead of the POST verb.

It's very easy to do it with javascript code, you can create AJAX code using the GET method and adding data to the requerst body as it's usually done with the POST method. For example, jQuery allows it: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ .

Comment: It would be nice to state the reason of the negative punctuation.

Comment: `POST is a "not secure method"` is not really correct. It is as secure as the protocol used. On `http` POST is arguably more secure than GET since it's easier to snoop on request URL then the request body. (I did not downvote)

Comment: max, you didn't understand the meaning of "not secure" in this context. GET is cacheable, and if the server follows standards, then you're sure the server state isn't changed. With POST that's not true, and by the way, you can send data in the request body as with POST, without encoding it in the url. So snooping is equally easy with both methods... :s .

Comment: Zanderwar, seriously. The correct way to go is use GET, not POST. GET is cacheable, so using it helps to improve performance, and preserves the www semantics. POST requests aren't cached by default, I'm not talking about "security" as you understood at all.

I'm being polite, but you're only adding noise to the conversation.

Answer (score -1):

While there are several potential solutions (cookies, custom headers, POST request) there are also very strong reasons why omitting the page number from the url is a really bad idea.

- State on the web is best represented by urls - we can pass them around to friends.
- Having the page number as parameter in the URL helps search engines to index your content.

In fact not updating the URL when doing pagination or flipping through a slider is really annoying since if you accidentally hit the back bar you have to click through the pagination again and try to find your way back.

[image: Copyright xkcd.com]

There are also pretty strong arguments that pagination belongs in the query string `news/world?page=2`  and not in the url proper `news/world/page/2`. One of which is  that pagination is a usually matter of presentation. If your designer decides that you should 500 entries per page your `news/world/page/2` should not suddenly break.